# How to prevent Visual Studio from auto formatting config files?

Tags: visual-studio

When opening solutions in Visual Studio and updating nuget packages, it appears as though Visual Studio automatically formats the App.config files by adding a blank space near the end of closing tags for some members on my team like so:

From:

```
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.0.0" newVersion="1.2.0.0"/>
```

To:

```
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.0.0" newVersion="1.2.0.0" />
```

This is frustrating as it only impacts some members in the team and I want to avoid having the file format constantly changing as it makes merging difficult. For example, I update the file and the spaces get removed, then someone else updates the file and spaces get added.

Why would this be and how could I stop this from happening?